# How many terms (non-simplified) does this polynomial have?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I'm currently doing a homework assignment and am trying to find a correlation between the number of terms the expanded version of a binomial/polynomial has.

I haven't yet gotten a formula to find a correlation, so I got stumped at this question...

```
(r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + x)^50
```

I've done binomials and found that the number of terms is simply 2^n terms. Or...

```
Number of terms for (x + y)^20 is 2^20
```

I'm having a hard time finding a correlation for the polynomial.

Edit: so I've found that the correlation is the number of terms to the power of the power is the number of coefficients there will be.

Is there a quick way to find how many terms there are after we combine them?

Comment: I don't think binomials have $2^n$ terms. For example, $(x+y)^2$ has only three terms

Comment: I was talking about uncombined, sorry!

Comment: What about $(x+y+z)^n$. How many terms?

Comment: From my calculations the number of uncombined terms should be 3^n. I'm having difficulty finding the # of combined terms now.

Comment: Take a look of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: To get combined terms you need to count how many solutions to sum of r nonnegative exponents = some number between 0 and n where you're expanding (x1+x2+...+xr)^n.